# WPF: switch back Grid visibility into first state (Collapsed) after animation

Tags: wpf, animation, grid, storyboard

So i have this `Grid`:

```
<Grid x:Name="notificarionGrid" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

And i want to change its Visibility value with animation, so i have this 2 Storyboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="fadeIn">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2.0"/>
        </Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Key="fadeOut">
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:2.0"/>
        </Storyboard>
```

Now this code works fine but the only problem here is that after the `fadeOut` my `Grid Visibility` become `Hidden` instead of `Collapsed` what cause some elements become not responsible under this `Grid`.

Any idea how to switch my `Grid` again to `Collapsed` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the `Completed` event for the `Storyboard`:

```
private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notificarionGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Storyboard x:Key="fadeOut" Completed="Storyboard_Completed">
    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:2.0"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Or add an `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` to your `Storyboard`:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="fadeOut">
    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:2.0"/>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Is it something that i cannot do via XAML ?

Comment: Yes, you could add an ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames to your Storyboard. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Add another ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames for the Visibility with an appropriate BeginTime:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="fadeOut">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                     To="0" Duration="0:0:2"/>

    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                   BeginTime="0:0:2">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```